# Azure OS disk and data Disk for Plesk

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, plesk

I am new to Azure VM. Just self-learning it now.
I setup a VM, and chosen a 64Gb data disk for it. However, after everything deployed, I found the VM has 2 disks, a OS disk which is 128Gb, then data disk 64Gb.

[image]

I also use Plesk which is a web hosting platform. As far as I can see, Plesk only accepts single disk directory which is my OS disk. Then my data disk is pointless?

[image]

And my last question is Plesk for Linux in Azure marketplace (https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en/marketplace/apps/plesk.plesk-onyx-linux?tab=PlansAndPrice)
Anyone knows what is the disk space 0G mean? No data disk but only default VM OS disk?

[image]

Thanks for helping. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone knows what is the disk space 0G mean? No data disk but only default VM OS disk?

The `Plesk` for `Linux` marketplace listing's **0GB** disc space indicates that the plan does not contain a `data disc`. If you require additional server storage for data storage, you will have to build a separate data disc. It implies that you will only have the `'OS'` disc that comes with the `'VM'.`

[image]

If you need more storage for your `Plesk` installation, you can always manually attach new data discs to your `Azure VM` depending on the `Azure portal` interface, the precise steps for adding data discs to a `Azure VM` can change.

Plesk can operate with a single `OS disc,` but it's recommended to add extra data discs to your `Azure VM` for larger or resource-intensive websites to ensure enough storage and speed. There are probably no more data discs included by default, but you can add them as needed. This is shown by the `0GB` disc space in the `Azure Marketplace` listing.

Comment: Let me know, if posted solution is helpful?